# New dryer got wet on ride home need advice

Tags: dryer

My wife and I bought a Maytag dryer it rained all the way home.  I wiped it down, plugged it in and it smelled. So if I let it set for a few days will it be ok?

Comment: Did you turn it on?  What did it smell like?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Maybe it'll be fine, maybe it'll burn your house down; there's no way for us to know from here. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

You might try drying it with a small room heater. Or opening it up and *gently* drying the electrical control board with a towel and then with a hair dryer. As @DanielGriscom states, we can't look into your dryer to see how wet it is.

That said, my own experience is that, left unplugged and given *time* and *warmth*, most electrical equipment can survive even immersion in fresh water. For battery-powered devices, remove the battery *immediately* to prevent electrolytic corrosion, and dry as above.

Comment: I would add though that most electrical equipment will survive, IF NOT ENERGIZED before drying out! By energizing it when wet, you may have unfortunately caused irreparable damage, especially to the electronics inside. At this point however it is what it is, so take that advice and dry it out with a hair dryer or something with forced air heat before even plugging it in again.